# Bash/shell script to run C console application on multiple unix/linux terminals

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, gnome-terminal

I have a multi-process **C** program for unix systems. I want to write a shell/bash script to run the **C** program mentioned above on multiple terminals (one for each execution of the program). That is: the script should run different terminals and execute the program on each terminal.
I have written this script, but it gives me a strange error on execution of support.sh, and the system is restarted.
Can you  help me?

```
/************************* Station.sh*****************************/

#!/bin/bash
type x-terminal-emulator >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
x-terminal-emulator -e ./support.sh ./Station 2304 2305 127.0.0.1 S
x-terminal-emulator -e ./support.sh ./Station 2305 2306 127.0.0.1 S
x-terminal-emulator -e ./support.sh ./Station 2306 2307 127.0.0.1 S
x-terminal-emulator -e ./support.sh ./Station 2307 2304 127.0.0.1 S
}

type x-terminal-emulator >/dev/null 2>&1 ||{
type gnome-terminal >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./support.sh ./Station 2304 2305 127.0.0.1 S"
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./support.sh ./Station 2305 2306 127.0.0.1 S"
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./support.sh ./Station 2306 2307 127.0.0.1 S"
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "./support.sh ./Station 2307 2304 127.0.0.1 S"
}
}

type x-terminal-emulator >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
type gnome-terminal >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
type xterm >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
xterm -e ./support.sh ./Station 2304 2305 127.0.0.1 S &
xterm -e ./support.sh ./Station 2305 2306 127.0.0.1 S &
xterm -e ./support.sh ./Station 2306 2307 127.0.0.1 S &
xterm -e ./support.sh ./Station 2307 2304 127.0.0.1 S &
}
}
}

type x-terminal-emulator >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
type gnome-terminal >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
type xterm >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "Nessun terminale conosciuto disponibile"
}
}


/*************************** support.sh************************/
#!/bin/bash
"$@"
exec "$SHELL"
```

Comment: "I've written this script that doesn't work.  Can you help me?"  It would help substantially if we could see the script. :)

Comment: I shared it on GDrive